# How to make owl carousel scroll smoothly like a marque tag ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, owl-carousel

I have a very simple client logo carousel, i am using owl carousel to make the logos move, i use the following code:

```
$('.manufacturer__logo__slider').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:40,
    responsiveClass:true,
    dots : false,
    navText : ['' , ''],
    nav:true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2,
        },
        400:{
            items:3,
        },
        600:{
            items:5,
        },
        1000:{
            items:6,
        },
        1920 : {
            items: 10
        }
    }
});
```

Link to demo **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/BUG/owlCarouselBug/)**, I basically want the logos to scroll continuously without even stopping for a mili secound , right now i have the following:

```
autoplaySpeed: 3000,
```

But the scroll stops for about half a secound after 3 secounds , i have gone through the documentation **[HERE](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html)** and there seems to be no property that allows the carousel to move smoothly , I have tried the following properties:

```
fluidSpeed: true,
smartSpeed: 3000,
```

But these seem to have no effect at all . How can i make my client slider carousel scroll contentiously without stopping ?

Comment: There is a customised version of owl carousel for smooth scroll here. 
https://codepen.io/mdrezwanferdous/pen/wpNZxN

Answer (score 2):

I know it may be late, but the solution is simple, just override the css property for transition:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    transition-timing-function: linear !important;
}
```